# SUM on joining fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I've 2 tables:

**Teams:**

```
|-- id -- username --|
|__ 1  __ user1    __|
|__ 2  __ user2    __|
|__ 3  __ user3    __|
```

**Payments:**

```
|-- id -- user_id -- amount --|
|__ 1  __ 1       __ 1000   --|
|__ 2  __ 1       __ 5000   --|
|__ 3  __ 2       __ 3000   --|
|__ 4  __ 1       __ 4500   --|
|__ 5  __ 2       __ 1000   --|
```

**I want to get users total payments. in single query.** result like this:

```
|-- user_id -- username -- total_payment --|
|__ 1       __ user1    __ 10500         --|
|__ 2       __ user2    __ 4000          --|
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want the `user_id` without `username`, there is no need for a join at all since the grouping need only happen against the `user_id` in `Payments`.

```
SELECT 
  user_id, 
  SUM(amount) AS total
FROM Payments
GROUP BY user_id
```

**Edit:** The question has since been edited to include the username in output, so use the query below -- a join *is* necessary.

If you want to join in the username, it is a simple addition to the `FROM` and `GROUP BY` clauses.

```
SELECT 
  Teams.user_id, 
  username,
  SUM(amount) AS total
FROM 
  Teams
  /* LEFT JOIN used in case a user has no payments -- will still show in the list */ 
  LEFT JOIN Payments ON Teams.user_id = Payments.user_id
GROUP BY 
  Teams.user_id, 
  Teams.username
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.user_id,B.user_name,A.total AS total_payment
FROM
(
SELECT 
  user_id, 
  SUM(amount) AS total
FROM Payments
GROUP BY user_id
) A,
Teams B
WHERE A.user_id = B.id;
```